# Upload image file: is compression on client side already possible?

Tags: javascript, html5

When offering photo file uploading, usually the user will have badly compressed and huge (10+ megapixels) JPEG files from their cameras or phones. On the server side, these files will get re-compressed to something like 800x600px and JPEG quality 7 or 8.

Is it (already) possible to do that re-compression on the client side? So that I would only need to transmit some 100kB (800x600px) and not 3 MB or more. Something like:

(1) With javascript's new FileSystem API ( http://slides.html5rocks.com/#filewriter ) it would be possible to read the photo file's data into client side JS.

(2) Then it would be necessary to re-encode the JPEG data, which is possible, but I counld not find any library for that (yet). Anybody knows such a library?

(3) Last step would be to POST the re-compressed JPEG data to the server side for storage and get a URL to the stored photo file back from the server for inclusion into the client's HTML.

I am looking for some jQuery plugin, other JS library or example web page that does this.

Comment: The [Is it possible to optimize/shrink images before uploading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983953/is-it-possible-to-optimize-shrink-images-before-uploading) question at StackOverflow presents several possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) supports html5 resizing of images and then uploading them, it also has fallbacks for unsupported browsers (IE *cough cough*) in Flash, Silverlight (and antiquated stuff like Google Gears and BrowserPlus).

Answer (score 2):

You can load the image onto a canvas element, resize it and then retrieve back the image to upload it.

Comment: For how to do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Answer (score 2):

Check out this demo: http://makeitsolutions.com/labs/jic

It's a javascript library created by me that solves that problem.

It allows you to compress jpg and png on the client side 100% with javascript and no external libraries required!